# When I link to my PHP file on my webserver, it will not load, but when I link to it on local WAMP server it works perfectly

Tags: php, webserver, timeout

I have build a website using jQuery, jQueryMobile, and HTML5. When I link to a php page stored in my local WAMP test server, it works perfectly fine, but when I link to it on my web server, it will not load and appears to be continuously trying to open the page. I have tried everything to try resolve this, by going through all of my lines of code to try and rectify the problem. I also have checked the settings on my web server, and they appear to be fine, and I have also asked a friend to put the file onto his webserver, and it will not work from his either

Below is the PHP file in question. Also just to note, I have saved the file type as a PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <title>Latest Info </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codiqa-cdn/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
          <h1>
              Parking Spaces
          </h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
              <body>
              <center>
<?php
$data = simplexml_load_file('http://www.dublincity.ie/dublintraffic/cpdata.xml');
$sectors = $data->children();
if($sectors){
    foreach($sectors as $sector){
        echo '<h2>'.$sector->getName().'</h2>';
        $carparks = $sector->children();
        if($carparks){
            foreach($carparks as $carpark){
                $attributes = $carpark->attributes();
                if($attributes){
                    foreach($attributes as $key=>$value){
                        echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br>';
                    }
                    echo '<hr>';
                }
            }


        }

    }
}
?>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when it eventually opens the page it says "undefined", I checked the error log on the webserver and it is empty

Comment: i loaded the page just fine. Can u verify if the hanging happens on "simplexml_load_file" or in nested loop?

Comment: ehm i'm not too sure. it loads fine for me on my local WAMP server, but when i upload it onto my webserver and test it there, it seems to display the theme but then nothing else, just a blank page.

Comment: Can I ask you what you did to get this running vlzvl?

Comment: just copied it, xml is public.. you can comment /**/ the problematic code one by one and test again to find where it hungs..

Comment: when you tested it, did you test it on a remote webserver or on a local webserver?

Comment: i tested it locally, in my XAMPP.. I have some remote servers to test it if its necessary.

Comment: yes, see it is working fine for me using WAMP, similar to XAMPP, when I upload the file onto my remote webserver, it just hangs and does not load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..just test it under 2 of my servers (**uhostall** & **gottohost**);
the code ran pretty well & fast.

I suggest to run `phpinfo()` in that specific remote server and search for:

```
libxml
```

Check if its active because this is a *requirement* for [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).

Although this is enabled by default in PHP5 (*correction: after 5.1.2*), it could be disabled by *--disable-simplexml*

Comment: excellent, i decided to open a free hosting account on uhostall, and i uploaded the file to their and it worked perfectly, thank you for all of your help!